# get curren value of box.sequence in tarantool

Tags: tarantool

I got sequence current value `3`

```
localhost:3401> box.sequence.S:next()
---
- 3
...
```

I can't find current value in the object

```
localhost:3401> box.sequence.S
---
- step: 1
  id: 1
  min: 1
  cache: 0
  uid: 1
  max: 9223372036854775807
  cycle: false
  name: S
  start: 1
...
```

How to get current value? Didn't find any way in documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, your sequence `S` has `id=1`

There is system space `box.space._sequence_data` which has current values of all sequences. All you need to do is just select your sequence id from the space: `box.space._sequence_data:select(1)`.

For example, `my_seq` is 4th sequence in my database.

```
tarantool> my_seq = box.schema.sequence.create('MySeq', {start=111})
---
...

tarantool> box.space._sequence_data:select(my_seq.id)
---
- []
...

tarantool> my_seq:next()
---
- 111
...

tarantool> box.space._sequence_data:select(my_seq.id)
---
- - [4, 111]
```

As you can see, right after creation `_sequence_data` doesn't have any details about new sequence until first use of `my_seq:next()` which 
initialises the sequence.

As you can see `box.space._sequence_data:select(my_seq.id)` returns tuple with number of the sequence and current value.

Please be aware of absence of guarantees for this method. And there are some issues with replication.

In 2.4.1 `sequence:currval()` is introduced: https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool/issues/4752